# asp.net mvc html.dropdownlist error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

CS1928: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'DropDownList' and the best extension method overload 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownList(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, string, string)' has some invalid arguments

I am  getting the user roles form the memebership provider and then asking the user to select the role. the roles are in a dropdown list on the register page.

```
public ActionResult ChangePassword() 
        {

            ViewData["PasswordLength"] = MembershipService.MinPasswordLength;
            var roles = Roles.GetAllRoles().ToList();       
            ViewData["Roles"] = new SelectList(roles);

            return View();
        }

<p>
               <%= Html.DropDownList("Userrole",((SelectList)ViewData["Roles"]).Items,"--Select One---") %>
                </p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
  <%= Html.DropDownList("Userrole",((SelectList)ViewData["Roles"]),"--Select One---") %>
```

**update**

There is something else that is causing the issue(do you have other extensions for the DropDownlist?)

The following works for me:

Action

```
 public ActionResult About()
        {
            var x = new List<string>
            {
                "A", "B", "C"
            };
            var y = new SelectList(x);
            ViewData["z"] = y;
            return View();
        }
```

View

```
 <%= Html.DropDownList("Userrole",((SelectList)ViewData["z"]),"--Select One---") %>
```

Comment: It's giving me this error when i dont have that

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'Userrole'.

Comment: I copy pasted and ran the same code that you sent me , it still throws the above error.

Comment: Sorry ,I got it , I made the changes as your code and it looks good now. Thank You so much Raj , appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

controller code

```
  public ActionResult About()
    {
        var x = new []
        {
            "A", "B", "C"
        };
        var y = new SelectList(x);
        ViewData["z"] = y;
        return View();
    }
```

it is your view code
you try this  it is working fine

```
<%: Html.DropDownList("Userrole", ViewData["z"] as SelectList,"--selectone--")%>
```